# determine which event is currently triggered in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

if I'm fetching multiple events using jquery how can I determine which event is currently triggered so I can processed further, for example

```
$("#someId").on('paste blur', function (e) {
   var data = '';
  // if paste
     data =  e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text')
  // if blur
     data =  $("#someId").val();        
});
```

Comment: `e.type` gives event type fired. But, if different events do completly different things, for readability, bind different handler

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.type` to get the current event,

```
$("#someId").on('paste blur', function (e) {
    if ('paste' == e.type) {
        data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text')
    } else if ('blur' == e.type) {
        data = $("#someId").val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Event.type`](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/).

```
$("#someId").on('paste blur', function (e) {
  var data = '';
  if(e.type == 'paste') {
    data =  e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text')
  }

  if(e.type == 'blur') {
    data =  $("#someId").val();        
  }
});
```

You might wish to consider registering separate handlers depending on how different you're going to handle the events though.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid unnecessary if conditions you can add only the events you actually needs:

```js
// Bind up a couple of event handlers
$("#txt").on({
  click: function() {
    console.log("click")
  },
  mouseout: function() {
    console.log("mouseout")
  },
  change: function() {
    console.log("change")
  }
});

//Lookup events for this particular Element
//prints out an object with all events on that element
console.log($._data($("#txt")[0], "events"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```